# get Integrated authentication username in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

Frontend - MS Access,
Backend - linked tables in SharePoint

Problem - in my FE I need to obtain the Username of the app (the integrated authentication Username that is connecting to linked tables on SharePoint)

Using  Environ would not work for me as it returns only Windows username.

```
Public Function GetUserName()
    GetUserName = Environ("UserName")
End Function
```

Is there a way to obtain integrated authentication Username?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Does this help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-user-identity-and-properties-in-sharepoint or https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255264/sharepoint-api-and-vba-access-denied#:~:text=The%20approach%20to%20get%20this%20token%20is%20to,PowerShell%20example%20and%20converted%20to%20VBA%20code.%20https%3A%2F%2Fblogs.technet.microsoft.com%2Fsharepointdevelopersupport%2F2018%2F02%2F07%2Fsharepoint-online-active-authentication%2F

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but no, this does not help.  I need to get the info on the login credentials with which Acces FE is currently connecting linked table (in this case SharePoint list)

Comment: Can't you create a table : tblUser, that has the UserName info linked with the authentication username ? Based on this crosscheck you should get the correct data.